# Error caused by RegEx?

Tags: java, regex

I'm using a system where I need to enter hundreds of RegEx expressions.  I've recently changed a few things and am getting the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: ?+* follows nothing in expression

I've no idea what this means and would really appreciate any pointers for what I should be looking for to fix it.

Many thanks :)

Katie

Comment: I think a good first step would be to post the actual regex that's causing the error.

Comment: Seems you have a `?`, `+` or `*` at the beginning of your expression.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the problem - I have hundreds of expressions and I'm not able to tell which one's causing the problem.  I was hoping for some tips on what I should be looking out for!

Comment: Shouldn't the stack trace show the line in which the error occurs?

Comment: Thanks Felix - I do have a * at the beginning of some expressions - is that bad?

Comment: `*` is a quantifier which means *match zero or more occurrences of the preceding pattern*. If there is no pattern, then it does not know what to do (hence the error). If you want to match a literal `*`, you have to escape it.

Comment: I'm editing the regex through the system's interface.  There's more to the error than I've posted.  Would it help if I pasted that?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious interpretation is that you have a regex that starts with a `'?'`, a `'+'` or a `'*'` meta-character.  Maybe it should have been escaped.  Maybe you've accidentally deleted the preceding things that is "quantified" by the meta-character.

> I do have a `'*'` at the beginning of some expressions - is that bad?

Yup.  If that is supposed to match a literal asterisk character, it must be preceded by a `'\'` to escape it.  (And as Felix Kling pointed out, the `'\'` will itself need to be escaped if the regex is embedded in a Java string literal.)

> Should I be putting `'.*'` (ie. dot star) instead?

It depends what you want the regex to match at that point.  `'.*'` means "eagerly match zero or more characters".  If that's what you mean, that's what you should use.

Comment: I guess in Java you have to use ``\\`` to escape it as the expression is specified as a string.

Comment: Many thanks all - I'll trawl through to see whether I've started with a \*.  I think I have.  Should I be putting .* (ie. dot star) instead?

Answer (score 0):

It means you have a quantifier (+,?, or *) that isn't quantifying anything. My guess is you might have forgotten to escape one of those characters (with \) when trying to match it.

Comment: I've located the problem!  Thanks so much all - it was all caused by a * at the beginning of the expression and I've changed it to .* and everything's good :)

Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you worked it out! you should accept whichever answer helped you fix the problem